# Stress test a substrated based blockchain

Tags: testing

Are there any tools/script to stress a substrate bases blockchain? Generating transfers between accounts should be Ok.
I think I saw one a few months ago but I can't find it :-(

Thanks very much.
Regards;
fernando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can benchmark your chain:

- https://docs.substrate.io/test/benchmark/#benchmarking-tools

Take a look at these transfer benchmarks:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b8c3d8cc2301a46070ddc9dbd90c135f9db5cd0d/frame/balances/src/benchmarking.rs#L38-L177

Additional info:

- https://youtu.be/Qa6sTyUqgek?t=576

Answer (score 3):

There is [sTPS repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-stps/) contains some functions to spin up a multi-node network and stress-test it.
Unfortunately there are some non-deterministic bugs with how we are using Zombienet which does not allow for reliable output.

You could still re-use some of the code in that repo, especially the Rust code regarding the transaction signing and sending.

I don't know what kind of benchmark you want to do. The sTPS aims at a multi-node global spanning benchmark, not just local testing.
Also, what are you expecting as output? Just transactions per second or other metrics like memory usage or response time?
Anyway, next time please include as *much* info as possible into your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this https://socket.dev/npm/package/artillery-engine-substrate but I have not used it yet unfortunately.